# Evaluate expressions as well as regex in single field in custom processors of Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

In my custom processor I have added  below field

```
public static final PropertyDescriptor CACHE_VALUE = new PropertyDescriptor.Builder()
            .name("Cache Value")
            .description("Cache Value")
            .required(true)
            .addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_EMPTY_VALIDATOR)
            .expressionLanguageSupported(ExpressionLanguageScope.FLOWFILE_ATTRIBUTES)
            .build();
```

Where I expect to read flowfile attributes like ${fieldName}
as well as regex like .* to read full content or some part of content like $.nodename.subnodename

For that I have added below code

```
for (FlowFile flowFile : flowFiles) {
                final String cacheKey = context.getProperty(CACHE_KEY).evaluateAttributeExpressions(flowFile).getValue();
                String cacheValue = null;
                cacheValue = context.getProperty(CACHE_VALUE).evaluateAttributeExpressions(flowFile).getValue();
                if (".*".equalsIgnoreCase(cacheValue.trim())) {
                    final ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    session.exportTo(flowFile, bytes);
                    cacheValue = bytes.toString();
                }
                cache.put(cacheKey, cacheValue);
                session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS);
            }
```

How to achieve this one some part of content like $.nodename.subnodename.
    Do I need to parse the json or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will either have to parse the JSON yourself, or use an `EvaluateJsonPath` processor before reaching this processor to extract content values out to attributes via JSON Path expressions, and then in your custom code, reference the value of the attribute.